# Can the supremum of continuous functions be discontinuous at every point of an interval?

Tags: real-analysis

Pether Luthy gave an example of a sequence of continuous real valued functions whose supremum was discontinuous on a set of positive measure. But does it exist a sequence of continuous real valued functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x)$ is a discontinuous function at every point of a subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

If such a sequence does not exist, how is it possible to prove it?

Comment: Are you asking for a sequence of continuous real valued functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $f(x) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x)$ is discontinuous on a subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: When you mention Peter Luthy's example, you mean the answer to this question, right: [Can the supremum of continuous functions be discontinuous on a set of positive measure?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/78511)

Comment: Yes, I am asking for a sequence of continuous real valued functions such that $f(x) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x)$ is discontinuous on a subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, Martin, I mean the answer to that question.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao The OP wants the function to be discontinuous at *every* point in the interval.

Answer (score 29):

Since the function $f$ is supremum of a set of continuous functions, it is [lower-semicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity).<sup>1</sup>

Every lower semicontinuous function belongs to the first [Baire class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function).<sup>2</sup>

If $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is of the first Baire class, then the set $D_f$ of the points of discontinuity is a [meager set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set).<sup>3</sup>

In particular, $D_f$ cannot be an interval.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Theorem 10.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA61)  in van Rooij-Schikhof: *A Second Course on Real Functions*. Mathematics Stack Exchange: [To show that the supremum of any collection of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1662726) or [Show that the supremum of a collection of lower semicontinuous function is lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2320814).

<sup>2</sup>[Theorem 10.6](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA64) and [Exercise 11.E](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA66) in van Rooij-Schikhof; [Show that lower semicontinuous function is the supremum of an increasing sequence of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1279763) on Mathematics Stack Exchange

<sup>3</sup>[Theorem 11.4](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA67) in van Rooij-Schikhof; MathOverflow: [Points of continuity of Baire class one functions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/32033)

Comment: One can bypass the ``lsc implies Baire-1'' step by noting directly that Angelo's $f$ is Baire-1, since one has for $g_n = \sup\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ that $f=\lim g_n$ pointwise.